# Magento 1.9 cron timeout 240 seconds

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, timeout

I got a cron job which creates products. There are many products, so the cron runs more than every 4 hours.

I create my products in batches of 250 and with paging. If I create every batch/page single wise, there is no error.

If I run the cron job as it should be (all product batches in row), then I get a timeout.

```
[27-Sep-2018 13:09:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded in /../magento/app/Mage.php on line 0
```

This is the file and line, where this error comes from, varies from time to time...

on top of my importer file I call this, because I hoped it would help...

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```

`php_ini` max_execution_time is set to 18000... where does this 240 come from and how can I change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.9 product import - timeout 240 seconds occurs - WHY? please help](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244523/magento-1-9-product-import-timeout-240-seconds-occurs-why-please-help)

Comment: can someone please help me? Its urgent!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop might be endless. If it is not, you could extend the maximum execution time like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

i hope this could help you.

Comment: it is not endless. It just takes some hours (13.000 products). I used ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1); and it did not work.. so why should 300 work?

Comment: I think your php.ini is over ridding your ini_set('max_execution_time','-1') function in magento/app/Mage.php. Can you verify it?

Comment: my php.ini is set to 12000 so there are no 240 seconds

Comment: Create a file with <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> in, and visit the file. You can verify max execution time there

Comment: max_execution_time = 18000