# Magento 1.9 product import - timeout 240 seconds occurs - WHY? please help

Tags: timeout

I got a cron job which creates products. There are many products, so the cron runs more than every 4 hours.

I create my products in batches of 250 and with paging. If I create every batch/page single wise, there is no error.

If I run the cron job as it should be (all product batches in row), then I get a timeout.

```
[27-Sep-2018 13:09:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded in /../magento/app/Mage.php on line 0
[01-Oct-2018 08:41:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded in /../magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 730
[01-Oct-2018 08:52:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded in /../magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 574
```

the file and line, where this error comes from, varies from time to time...

on top of my importer file I call this, because I hoped it would help...

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```

`php_ini` max_execution_time is set to 18000... where does this 240 come from and how can I change it?

Comment: can someone please help me? it is urgent!